# Uncaught CurlException: 7: Failed to connect

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have a live facebook application. Starting from last week, I keep getting

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught CurlException: 7: Failed to connect to 2a03:2880:2110:3f03:face:b00c:0:1: Network is unreachable

It is thrown in base-facebook.php file in facebook sdk 3.1.1 (Using the latest version)

What could be the cause? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe,you should check Network settings for IPV6.

at My application , Error continued to occur .
Setting up the network and Programming has not changed.

So , I've change Network settings for IPV6. I've solved it.

Comment: +1, the error is your server not being able to reach Facebook over IPV6. If you cannot resolve the issue by fixing the network, a quick workaround is to disable the IPV6 interface on your server

Comment: Igy, can you explain how can we disable IPV6 Interface?